# Using IPv6 as seed + time almost as good as TRNG?

Tags: randomness

I just figured out a way to create a RNG that may be almost as good as TRNG (true random number generator) and need some input to confirm/clarify.

What if I use the IPv6 address of a visitor as a seed + the time recorded when the visitor executes a particular action at my website to generate the random numbers?

IPv6 has about 340 trillion trillion trillion possible addresses.

And I increase the strength by repeating the same process with a 2nd visitor and do some logic between 1st visitor's RNG and 2nd visitor's RNG to arrive at a new RNG (say "1st New").

And I continue with the same process on 3rd visitor and do some logic between 3rd visitor's RNG and "1st New" to arrive at another new RNG (say "2nd New").

And I continue with the same on subsequent visitors until a certain duration is reached, to arrive at a final RNG (say "Final New").

Is this "Final New" almost as good as TRNG?
Or is it at least as good as CSPRNG?

For a hacker to successfully brute force my RNG, he needs to know the specific IP addresses of my visitors, at certain time period when a particular (unknown) action is executed, per each different visitor, for a duration of time, and the logic used in computing the RNG from one visitor with the next.

Comment: If you're looking for a non dedicated hardware TRNG, investigate [haveged](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged). It kinda builds upon internal system timings somewhat like your access times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this "Final New" almost as good as TRNG [or CSPRNG]?

Assuming proper cryptographic techniques for entropy combination (eg Fortuna or at least hashing) are used for the combination of the "RNGs" the answer is **no**. If this kind of processing is not used, then the answer is an even bigger **NO**.

The reason here is relatively simple, the combination of IPv6 adress paired with the timing of the visit *isn't actually a secret only known to you*. Whoever hosts your VPS / your physical machine / provides you with internet connectivity or provides your ISP with internet connectivity can *collect the very data you are considering random*. And in cryptography the job of a TRNG / CSPRNG is to provide *unpredictable* random bytes, which is clearly violated here, because some or more of your network / system operators can predict the "random" bytes.

*Additionally*, while there are indeed $2^{128}$ IPv6 adresses, *only a tiny fraction* of these are used by actual end-users, so they're indeed not as unpredictable as assumed. Also *because* IPv6 has such a vast adress space, end-users tend to get static adresses (unlike with IPv4 where they are actually dynamic quite often) and so if you have a standard set of users, their IPv6 adresses won't give all that much unpredictability.

*However*, if you really want to use this idea, you can still measure this data (the IP + time pair and maybe also do this for IPv4?) and *feed it to your operating system as additional entropy / seed data*, which can't hurt security due to the way this data is used by the OS.

Comment: I've considered using IPv4 too but despite being dynamic it has a total of several billions addresses only, making any brute force attempt fairly easy.